# How to disable CORS on localhost using expressjs

Tags: express

I want to disable CORS on localhost for a specific url, here is my code

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 3000

    app.use(express.static('files'))

    app.all('/no-cors/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "fake");
      next();
    });

    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

    app.get('/sample-json', (req, res) => res.json({"foo": "bar"}));

    // it shld show error in console
    app.get('/no-cors/sample-json', (req, res) => {
      res.json({"cors": "off"});
    });
    app

.listen(port, () => console.log(Example app listening on port 3000'))
```

but I open `http://localhost:3000/no-cors/sample-json` it still show me the json.

Answer (score 0):

Path argument in `express().get(path,...)` is evaluated as whole string. Path in Express (and URL generally, not only in Express) does not work as folder structure.

That’s why the address /no-cors/sample-json is not catched with your `app.all()`.

If you want it to work, try the path as `/no-cors/*`